# Calculating Intra-Assay Coefficient of Variance

Tags: neuroscience, clinical-psychology

I am using cortisol data for my master's thesis and I need to report inter-assay and intra-assay coefficient of variance [CV]. In my study, we collected vials of saliva at 5 different time points. The lab that assayed our samples gave us intra-assay CVs for the 5 vials. How do I calculate the overall intra-assay coefficient of variance? Do I calculate an average of all 5 CVs for each participant, then average down the column to get one overall CV%? OR, do I average down the column for each CV, and report the 5 different CVs?

[image]